# Get Original Variable Name From Function in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to be able to get the original name of the variable that was passed into a function sort of like this:

```
def orig_var_name(var)
  var.calling_method_arg_name # or something
end

orig_var_name(my_var)
#--> "my_var"
```

Is something like this possible in Ruby? I am currently using 2.3.1, but I am not bound to this version.

Comment: Nope, not possible. Not directly, at least. You could inspect the stack, get the location of the calling function, read the source file and find it that way, possibly. But it's hacky, not guaranteed to work, and it's probably a symptom of an XY problem. Why do you need it?

Comment: @Amadan, I have a template file with some ruby code in it. There is a method that pulls some text from the database based on the name of the variable that is passed to it. Then, that variable's value is set to the returned text and rendered. I could add another parameter to the template method like this
`render_text(my_var, "my_var")`
but this is not very dry and I would like to make it simpler on the users. In this case, there would be a row in the database with a "my_var" key in and some text as a value.

Comment: Would I be able to do this if I passed a symbol in as the argument instead of just a normal variable?
`orig_var_name(:my_var) #--> :my_var`

Comment: Okay, I got it working by using symbols and doing both the db lookup and the variable assignment and rendering in the same method. I still have not been able to access the original variable name in an efficient way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementation of the idea from the comment, but I reiterate that it's extremely fragile and a really bad idea all around.

```
def orig_var_name(var)
  loc = caller_locations.first
  line = File.read(loc.path).lines[loc.lineno - 1]
  line[/#{__method__}\(\s*(\w+)\s*\)/, 1]
rescue Errno::ENOENT
  raise "Not usable from REPL"
end

foo = 1
puts orig_var_name(foo)
# => foo
```

Comment: I definitely don't want to be using something this fragile, especially since this will be running on a public server. I can work around it, as I mentioned above, but it will not be as simple as the end users will desire.

Comment: I went ahead and marked this as correct because it does answer the question I asked. To anyone else wondering about this sort of thing, you can probably rearrange your code in such a way so as to avoid needing to do this.